# How to create a DB for MongoDB container on start up?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am working with Docker and I have a stack with PHP, MySQL, Apache and Redis. I need to add MongoDB now so I was checking the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/4a81205a13fefc418355248f750551e4f7c62361/3.4/Dockerfile) for the latest version and also [the docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/4a81205a13fefc418355248f750551e4f7c62361/3.4/docker-entrypoint.sh) file from the [MongoDB Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mongo/) but I couldn't find a way to setup a default DB, admin user/password and possibly auth method for the container from a `docker-compose.yml` file.

In MySQL you can setup some ENV variables as for example:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
```

And this will setup the DB and the user/password as the `root` password.

Is there any way to achieve the same with MongoDB? Anyone has some experience or workaround?

Comment: can you create a container based on mysql and set it up as you want and then use it?

Comment: @Valentin of course I can but what is your point?

Comment: My point is, that you can set up a default DB, admin user/password and possibly auth method in dockerfile using variables and then pass them in compose file

Comment: Note: If using any of the solutions that use mongo-init script, please make sure you set restart: unless-stopped (or something besides no) for containers dependent on mongo.  This is because these containers will fail to connect to mongo the first time while it initializes (even with depends_on flag).  See this thread for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y/35170810#35170810

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Here another cleaner solution by using `docker-compose` and a `js` script.

This example assumes that both files (docker-compose.yml and mongo-init.js) lay in the same folder.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    mongodb:
        image: mongo:latest
        container_name: mongodb
        restart: always
        environment:
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: <admin-user>
            MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <admin-password>
            MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: <database to create>
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        volumes:
            - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

### mongo-init.js

```
db.createUser(
        {
            user: "<user for database which shall be created>",
            pwd: "<password of user>",
            roles: [
                {
                    role: "readWrite",
                    db: "<database to create>"
                }
            ]
        }
);
```

Then simply start the service by running the following docker-compose command

```
docker-compose up --build -d mongodb
```

**Note**: The code in the docker-entrypoint-init.d folder is only executed if the database has never been initialized before.

Comment: You have to replace all <> values in the snippet with your settings.

Comment: Yes, not full copypaste.

Comment: what is mongo-init.js:ro ?

Comment: @HerilMuratovic, the `volumes` entry `./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro` is linking the local file `./mongo-init.js` to the container path `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js` as read-only `ro`. You can find more details about how to use *volumes* here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Thank you @PaulWasilewski! I didn't know that "ro" is flag for readonly.

Comment: I am attempting to follow this solution but I am not able to get it to work. Mongo's debugging tool mentions: `[main] directory [/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js] doesn't have any *.js files`. You sure this works for *.js files?

Comment: @GustavoSilva I am absolutely sure it’s working. It seems that your docker compose file and the js script are not in the same folder. Or are you working on windows? Then please adjust the `volumes` option and add the absolute path to the `mongo-init.js` file for example `c:\docker\mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro`.

Comment: Hum, wouldn't it work if compose file and the script are in different directory? I have obviously updated the paths. My volume section was `./path/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro` I am unsure whether this only works for this image tag. What do you say about that?

Comment: @GustavoSilva it’s not image related. You need to make sure that the path entries in the volumes option are right. So if the js script is not in the same directory then you have to set the path accordingly. Also your debug message indicates that the js script was not linked.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski Ok, thank you for your help. I believe in you and there has to be an issue with the paths then. Obrigado

Comment: @GustavoSilva and one more point, make sure that the file path can be shared with a docker container. Docker File Sharing Settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194303/discussion-between-gustavo-silva-and-paul-wasilewski).

Comment: @PaulWasilewski I've tried this solution but my Javascript file and directory structure is a little bit more complicated. If you have time, would you be willing to check out the question I've posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57209269/i-want-to-create-a-mongodb-database-and-populate-it-with-a-number-of-collections

Comment: What is db? The code seems incomplete to me, is that the mongoose connection?

Comment: The example is working and complete. `db` is the currently connected database. The `mongo-init.js` script is executed in a mongo shell environment once the container is created.

Comment: How to create multiple databases and users this way ?

Comment: In order for db.CreateUser to work, I had to first add items to the database.

Comment: OMFG @Lazor you're right! The same thing happened to me. Maddening!

Comment: FYI: `MongoDB only creates the database when you first store data in that database. This data could be a collection or even a document.` from this source https://www.mongodb.com/basics/create-database .

Comment: @phrogg @Lazor You don't have to store data first, but You have to select the database first like so `db = db.getSiblingDB(_getEnv("MONGO_DATABASE"));`

Then after selecting it, you can create your user(s).

Answer (score 145):

The docker hub [`mongo`](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mongo/) image will run any scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` when there is nothing populated in the `/data/db` directory.

#### Database Initialisation

The `mongo` container image provides the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` path to deploy custom `.js` or `.sh` setup scripts that will be run once on database initialisation. `.js` scripts will be run against `test` by default or `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` if defined in the environment.

```
COPY mysetup.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

or

```
COPY mysetup.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

A simple initialisation [mongo shell javascript](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/) file that demonstrates setting up the `container` collection with data, logging and how to exit with an error (for result checking).

```
let error = true

let res = [
  db.container.drop(),
  db.container.createIndex({ myfield: 1 }, { unique: true }),
  db.container.createIndex({ thatfield: 1 }),
  db.container.createIndex({ thatfield: 1 }),
  db.container.insert({ myfield: 'hello', thatfield: 'testing' }),
  db.container.insert({ myfield: 'hello2', thatfield: 'testing' }),
  db.container.insert({ myfield: 'hello3', thatfield: 'testing' }),
  db.container.insert({ myfield: 'hello3', thatfield: 'testing' })
]

printjson(res)

if (error) {
  print('Error, exiting')
  quit(1)
}
```

#### Admin User Setup

The environment variables to control "root" user setup are

- `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`
- `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`

Example

```
docker run -d \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin \
  -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password \
  mongod
```

or `Dockerfile`

```
FROM docker.io/mongo
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME admin
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD password
```

You don't need to use `--auth` on the command line as the docker `entrypoint.sh` script adds this in when it detects the environment variables exist.

Comment: This is excellent, I suppose `set -e` is telling the `entrypoint.sh` to read variables from `ENV` definition so I can use the same approach as the example from MySQL, I am right? As an addition to your answer I did found [this PR](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/pull/145) where apparently someone is working in something similar to your proposal just coming from another point of view

Comment: The environment variables you get by default. `set -e` causes the whole script to exit when a command fails, so the script can't silently fail and startup mongo.

Comment: Similar to all the Dockerfile build scripts you see that use `&&` everywhere.

Comment: That mongo PR is a much more thorough implementation! and the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory makes it extensible. I hope that get's merged

Comment: It's merged (see [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/pull/145))

Comment: I am having issues initializing an empty DB using `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` since I think a script is needed. Could you add a small example for such script for a database named container?

Comment: @ReynierPM added an example init

Comment: how the custom script will work with docker compose?

Comment: @jzqa You can set the [environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)  in compose. Possibly mount the init files from a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes), but it's probably better to build a `Dockerfile` for that.

Comment: @Matt how would you populate collections other than users? For instance a table in mongo named 'settings'?

Comment: @boydenhartog With the javascript files in the `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory

Comment: @Matt yea I figured that much but so far I have only come across examples where users are created. There's hardly any documentation on this functionality. For instance in the example above where the db object is coming from and what methods it has.

Comment: @boydenhartog oh right... that's the mongo javascripty [shell environment](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/), so scripts run in what you use as the `mongo` command via `mongo script.js`. I've added that to the answer

Comment: @Matt thats exactly the info that I was missing. Thanks!!

Comment: when there is nothing populated in the /data/db directory.

this part is really saved my life.

Answer (score 96):

No need to create a database in advance (they're created on the fly), but it makes sense to create a non-root user the first time the container starts.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
  ...
  mongo:
    image: mongo:6-jammy
    env_file: .env-mongo
    volumes:
      - mongo:/data/db
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js
      # - ./init-mongo.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.sh  # mongo < 6

volumes:
  mongo:
```

`init-mongo.sh` doesn't need to be executable. It's sourced.

`.env` (app's variables):

```
MONGO_USER=user
MONGO_PASSWORD=userpasswd
MONGO_DB=foo
```

`.env-mongo` (mongo service's variables):

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpasswd
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=foo  # for mongo >= 6
```

Since `mongo-6` one can use `process.env`, so use `init-mongo.js`. Before that, use `init-mongo.sh` (change the script that you attach in `docker-compose.yml`, and `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` is not needed in this case).

`.env` is meant to be used by the app service(s), `.env-mongo` by the `mongo` service.

`MONGO_INITDB_*` variables are used by the `mongo`'s entrypoint. The docs can be found on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo). Also it's the entrypoint that [runs](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/840d7ed246dc72ae9e84ce92b9f5a6f9dfa4d6e1/6.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L384-L391) the initialization script.

`init-mongo.js`:

```js
db.getSiblingDB('admin').auth(
    process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME,
    process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
);
db.createUser({
    user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
    pwd: process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD,
    roles: ["readWrite"],
});
```

`init-mongo.sh`:

```bash
q_MONGO_USER=`jq --arg v "$MONGO_USER" -n '$v'`
q_MONGO_PASSWORD=`jq --arg v "$MONGO_PASSWORD" -n '$v'`
mongo -u "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME" -p "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD" admin <<EOF
    use foo;
    db.createUser({
        user: $q_MONGO_USER,
        pwd: $q_MONGO_PASSWORD,
        roles: ["readWrite"],
    });
EOF
```

More files in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/c229b3f9e8282ea12cecbbe923cc61c1).

Comment: I just spent 3hrs around searching for how to create my own db initially. Crazy that documentation does not mention that you need to authenticate within .js or .sh files. Examples over the internet are not complete at all. You literally need to dig into their .sh script to conclude how to write this stuff. How to "create empty database" when container starts. PR should be created for this to be simplified. A little bit crazy if you ask me.

Comment: I spent hours looking for a solution to this problem. This just saved me. Thank you.

Comment: `$(cat "$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE")` should be replaced with `$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` these days because the Mongo image already handles the secret for us. https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Comment: It was so in [3.2](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/b808c630a16f3ad1024a0eefeda57ab2cc83a35c/3.2/docker-entrypoint.sh#L182) as well. I probably failed to notice.

Comment: @x-yuri What's the benefit of using configs for init-mongo.sh, rather than just copying the file to docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and letting it run there automatically?

Comment: @Lazor The upside of configs is that you don't have to store the file on the host filesystem. And by copying you probably mean building a custom image with the file being at the mentioned place. The downside of this approach apparently is that you need a custom image, whether it matters for you or not.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks for sharing!

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Starting from Mongodb version 6.0 the command mongo was replaced by mongosh

Comment: @JustRandom You can check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 70):

Here's a working solution that creates `admin-user` user with a password, additional database (`test-database`), and `test-user` in that database.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:4.0.3

ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME admin-user
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD admin-password
ENV MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE admin

ADD mongo-init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

mongo-init.js:

```
db.auth('admin-user', 'admin-password')

db = db.getSiblingDB('test-database')

db.createUser({
  user: 'test-user',
  pwd: 'test-password',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'root',
      db: 'test-database',
    },
  ],
});
```

The tricky part was to understand that *.js files were run unauthenticated.
The solution authenticates the script as the `admin-user` in the `admin` database. `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE admin` is essential, otherwise the script would be executed against the `test` db. Check the source code of [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/90f043506151539585d7894e3ade7fde6960674a/4.0/docker-entrypoint.sh).

Comment: Is there a typo in the roles? db should be test-database?

Comment: Two comments on the second line that has getSiblingDB. First, everything worked in my test without this line. Second, it seems like bad form to overwrite the db variable like this, since it is considered a global object and overwriting it changes the context for everything.

Comment: @Mateusz Stefek "MongoServerError: Could not find role: root@PosnicPro" role should be "readWrite"?

Answer (score 16):

In case someone is looking for how to configure MongoDB with authentication using `docker-compose`, here is a sample configuration using environment variables:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  db:
      image: mongo
      environment:
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
        - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=<YOUR_PASSWORD>
      ports:
        - "27017:27017"
```

When running `docker-compose up` your mongo instance is run automatically with auth enabled. You will have a admin database with the given password.

Comment: `mongo --username admin --password password --host localhost --port 27017` i am not able to connect as the logs show the users and db is created successfully. ERROR: `$ mongo --username admin --password password --host localhost --port 27017
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/
MongoDB server version: 3.6.5
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2018-06-07T13:05:09.022+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1461:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed`

Comment: you need to `mongo admin --username ADMIN --password PASSWORT` to connect to your mongo instance.

Comment: Can't get this to work. "Could not find user admin@admin". It doesn't seem to automatically create the user?

Comment: ```mongodb://root:example@localhost/my-db?authSource=admin```

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung I had this problem, noticed that i already had a volume created for database, you have to delete this volume for the container to create a new user.

Comment: Was having the same issue, but @DanielS. suggestion of deleting the volume fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.6
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 9229:9229

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8111:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=root
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=hello
```

**./mongo-init/init.js**

```js
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("MyDatabaseName");


db.myCollectionName.createIndex({ "address.zip": 1 }, { unique: false });

db.myCollectionName.insert({ "address": { "city": "Paris", "zip": "123" }, "name": "Mike", "phone": "1234" });
db.myCollectionName.insert({ "address": { "city": "Marsel", "zip": "321" }, "name": "Helga", "phone": "4321" });
```

Look at the dashboard by http://localhost:8111/:

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, what is the goal of exposing 9229? According to the reference e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/ mongod may be sitting on 27017,27018,27019 by default.

Comment: awesome example! Simple and clear!

Answer (score 14):

Just a quick add-on to a couple of answers here - that are all great, it indeed saved me a lot of time figuring things out!

I would add a bit of code if the user you want to create needs to be attached to a specific database

The main thing is that you need to be logged on your admin base to create new users.

So for `docker-compose.yml` examples, your `mongo-init.js` file would look like:

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
// move to the admin db - always created in Mongo
db.auth("rootUser", "rootPassword");
// log as root admin if you decided to authenticate in your docker-compose file...
db = db.getSiblingDB('DB_test');
// create and move to your new database
db.createUser({
'user': "dbUser",
'pwd': "dbPwd",
'roles': [{
    'role': 'dbOwner',
    'db': 'DB_test'}]});
// user created
db.createCollection('collection_test');
// add new collection
```

If that can help someone, I'm happy - cheers,

Comment: This is the only answer that's still working. Though the `createCollection` call seems unnecessary.

Comment: The only working solution with latest mongo (as of 2024)

Answer (score 10):

Given this `.env` file:

```
DB_NAME=foo
DB_USER=bar
DB_PASSWORD=baz
```

And this `mongo-init.sh` file:

```bash
mongo --eval "db.auth('$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME', '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD'); db = db.getSiblingDB('$DB_NAME'); db.createUser({ user: '$DB_USER', pwd: '$DB_PASSWORD', roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: '$DB_NAME' }] });"
```

This `docker-compose.yml` will create the admin database and admin user, authenticate as the admin user, then create the real database and add the real user:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
#  app:
#    build: .
#    env_file: .env
#    environment:
#      DB_HOST: 'mongodb://mongodb'

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin-user # change this
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin-password # change this
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/data/db
      - ./mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: Any reason you use sh when all you do is just eval a js line? Why not use a js file?

Comment: @MaxO. It might be possible to do the same thing with a `mongo-init.js` file - can it read the environment variables from `process.env`?

Comment: That's possible with `_getEnv()` (version >= 4.7.0) and I believe it's also possible with just using the $

Answer (score 10):

This is how I do it using env variables and secrets.

Following will create "app_user" and "app_database" on mongo container startup (only if used database stored in /data/db is empty).

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mongo:5.0.3

COPY images/mongo/init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**init.js**

```
db.log.insertOne({"message": "Database created."});

db.createUser(
    {
        user: _getEnv("MONGO_USER"),
        pwd: cat(_getEnv("MONGO_PASSWORD_FILE")),
        roles: [
            "readWrite", "dbAdmin"
        ]
    }
);
```

- Script will use MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE (env variable defined in docker-compose.yml) for database name.
- Scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ will only be run if used database stored in /data/db is empty.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
mongo:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./images/mongo/Dockerfile
  container_name: app_mongo
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: "app_database"
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/app_mongo_root_password
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "root"
    MONGO_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/app_mongo_password
    MONGO_USER: "app_user"
  secrets:
    - app_mongo_password
    - app_mongo_root_password
  volumes:
    - mongo:/data/db

secrets:
  app_mongo_password:
    file: ./secrets/app_mongo_password.txt
  app_mongo_root_password:
    file: ./secrets/app_mongo_root_password.txt

volumes:
  mongo:
```

Comment: Where does that `_getEnv` function in `init.js` come from?

Comment: From Mongo - https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/257#issuecomment-824117838

Comment: Good to note that a newer version is required for this: >= 4.7.0

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking to remove usernames and passwords from your docker-compose.yml you can use **Docker Secrets**, here is how I have approached it.

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  db:
    image: mongo:3
    container_name: mycontainer
  secrets:
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
  environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE=/var/run/secrets/MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/var/run/secrets/MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
secrets:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:
    file:  secrets/${NODE_ENV}_mongo_root_username.txt
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:
    file:  secrets/${NODE_ENV}_mongo_root_password.txt
```

I have use the **file:** option for my secrets however, you can also use **external:** and use the secrets in a swarm.

The secrets are available to any script in the container at /var/run/secrets

The Docker documentation has this to say about storing sensitive data...

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

You can use secrets to manage any sensitive data which a container needs at runtime but you don’t want to store in the image or in source control, such as:

Usernames and passwords
TLS certificates and keys
SSH keys
Other important data such as the name of a database or internal server
Generic strings or binary content (up to 500 kb in size)

Answer (score 3):

My answer is based on the one provided by @x-yuri; but my scenario it's a little bit different. I wanted an image containing the script, not bind without needing to bind-mount it.

`mongo-init.sh` -- don't know whether or not is need but but I ran `chmod +x mongo-init.sh` also:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522699
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/37811764
mongo -- "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" <<EOF
  var rootUser = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME';
  var rootPassword = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD';
  var user = '$MONGO_INITDB_USERNAME';
  var passwd = '$MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD';

  var admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin');

  admin.auth(rootUser, rootPassword);
  db.createUser({
    user: user,
    pwd: passwd,
    roles: [
      {
        role: "root",
        db: "admin"
      }
    ]
  });
EOF
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mongo:3.6

COPY mongo-init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh

CMD [ "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh" ]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
    mongodb:
        build: .
        container_name: mongodb-test
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
            - MONGO_INITDB_USERNAME=myproject
            - MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD=myproject
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=myproject

    myproject:
        image: myuser/myimage
        restart: on-failure
        container_name: myproject
        environment:
            - DB_URI=mongodb
            - DB_HOST=mongodb-test
            - DB_NAME=myproject
            - DB_USERNAME=myproject
            - DB_PASSWORD=myproject
            - DB_OPTIONS=
            - DB_PORT=27017            
        ports:
            - "80:80"
```

After that, I went ahead and publish this Dockefile as an image to use in other projects.

note: without adding the `CMD` it mongo throws: *unbound variable error*

Answer (score 2):

Steps to create **multiple databases and users in MongoDB docker container without root access**.

1. Stop docker-compose with

   ```
   docker-compose down
   ```

   command, or `'docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml <...>'` if you have multiple files.
2. Remove volumes assigned to the mongo container. Run `'docker volume ls'`. If there is anything similar to `<projectfolder>_mongodb--vol`, remove it by applying

   ```
   docker volume rm <projectfolder>_mongodb--vol
   ```
3. Set up folder with `.js` or `.sh` mongo database [init scripts](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo). For example, `mongo-init/db_1.js`:

   ```js
   conn = new Mongo();
   db = conn.getDB("db_1")
   db.createUser(
   {
       user: "db_1_service_user",
       pwd: "<password>",
       roles: [
           {
               role: "readWrite",
               db: "db_1"
           }
       ]
   }
   );
   ```

   Repeat the procedure for `mongo-init/db_2.js` file. [conn.getDB()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) creates the database, db.createUser() creates a user and assigns it to the database.
4. docker-compose.yml fragment, notice the mount binding from `./mongo-init/` local folder containing database init scripts to the remote `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`:

   ```yaml
   version: "3.8"
   services:

     my-service_1:
       depends_on:
         - mongodb

     my-service_2:
       depends_on:
         - mongodb

     mongodb:
       image: mongo:4.4-bionic
       ports:
       - "27017:27017"
       volumes:
       - mongodb--vol:/data/db
       - ./mongo-init/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
       healthcheck:
       test: "echo 'db.runCommand(\"ping\").ok'"
       interval: 5s
       timeout: 5s
       retries: 3

   # in-service volumes are very slow in MacOS and Windows, 
   # so using fast shared volumes for large storage
   volumes:
       mongodb--vol:
   ```
5. Apply connection strings to your applications:

   ```
   mongodb://db_1_service_user:<password>@mongodb:27017/db_1
   ```

   ```
   mongodb://db_2_service_user:<password>@mongodb:27017/db_2
   ```

Answer (score 2):

*docker-compose.yml*

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: chat_history
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: ${MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - "${MONGO_INITDB_PORT}:27017"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./data/mongo:/data/db
      - ./scripts/docker/mongo/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

*mongo-init.js*

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
db.auth(
    process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME,
    process.env.MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD,
);

db = db.getSiblingDB(process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE);
db.createUser({
    user: process.env.MONGO_USER,
    pwd: process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD,
    roles: [{
        role: 'readWrite',
        db: process.env.MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE,
    }]
});

db.createCollection(process.env.MAIN_DB_COLLECTION);
```

First I've authorized the 'admin' user, then I've created a new table so that I could connect to it directly from the app (Go).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using docker-compose and are trying to run any of these suggestions after you have created a volume, you may need to delete the volume because the init script will not run if the volume already there.

To see if this is the case, try running:-

`docker volume ls`

If your mongo data is there, you should see it in a volume names something like:-

`<db>_<volume>`

If the volume is something like db_volume, you will need to run:-

```
docker volume rm db_volume
```

You may need to trash your container for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that MongoDB did not start up. My problem was that I specified a volume for the service, but did not specify it in the general section.

So, my configuration which worked, looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongodb/mongodb-community-server:latest
    container_name: mongodb
    environment:
      - MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGODB_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=Passw0rd
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=defaultdb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express:latest
    container_name: mongo-express
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL=mongodb://admin:Passw0rd@mongodb:27017/?authSource=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=Passw0rd
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=mexpress
      - ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=mexpress
    links:
      - mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
volumes:
  mongo_data:
```