# how to add --auth for mongodb image when using docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run my project created by node,mongodb,nginx;

and I have build the project using `docker build`

and then I use `docker up -d nginx` to start my project. but I haven't found the config to run mongodb image with '--auth', so how to add '--auth' when compose start the mongodb?

here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    expose:
        - "27017"
    volumes:
        - "/home/open/mymongo:/data/db"
  nginx:
    build: /home/open/mynginx/
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
        - "80:80"
    links:
        - node_server:node
  node_server:
    build: /home/laoqiren/workspace/isomorphic-redux-CNode/ 
    links:
        - mongodb:mongo
    expose:
        - "3000"
```

Comment: Why would you expose MongoDB's port the first place?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg It looks like a hangover from a v1 compose file. Exposing a port without mapping it from the docker host made it available to other containers. It doesn't do much in v2 onwards where compose creates a standalone docker network that has open communications between containers on that network

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Supply a `command` to the container including the `--auth` option.

```
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    expose:
        - "27017"
    volumes:
        - "/home/open/mymongo:/data/db"
    command: mongod --auth
```

The latest mongo containers come with ["root" auth initialisation via environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42917632/1318694) too, modelled on the postgres setup.

Comment: thanks, but why is it OK to just set command be  --auth?  I have read the dockerfile of mongodb image, I can't understand why its CMD is ['mongod']  and its entrypoint is docker-entrypoint.sh, but I can run the image by 'docker run mongo --auth', since the --auth will replace the mongod CMD, so it will be '--auth' not 'mongod --auth', why it can run?

Comment: The image defaults to running `mongod` when nothing is supplied and also when arguments starting with a `-` are supplied. Otherwise it will run the command you provide.

Comment: but  the document said if ENTRYPOINT and CMD are both provided, the value in CMD will be default parameter of ENTRYPOINT, so why the --auth will not replace the mongod but be added to CMD? --auth is also a parameter.

Comment: I'm not sure which document you are referring to, but I believe [this is the code in the entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/812b8fb401a929c312c7222a26b707a6415450c6/3.4/docker-entrypoint.sh#L4-L6) that is causing the confusion.