# How to pass docker run command line arg to docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

mongo docker image can be started using some command like this:

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo --auth
```

This works fine, but now my cloud service provider is using docker-compose, and I don't have access to docker run, all I can do is to modify that .yml file that used with docker-compose.

So my question is how can I pass that --auth command line arg to docker-compose using that .yml config file? Or do I understand this in a totally wrong way? Anyway I just want to start my mongo image with auth enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered earlier here([how to add --auth for mongodb image when using docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121897/how-to-add-auth-for-mongodb-image-when-using-docker-compose)). auth here is an option to mongo container. In docker compose, we can specify the same in "command" parameter.