# docker-compose mongodb access env variables in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ script

Tags: mongodb, docker

This question is based off the top answer to [a previous question on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912755/how-to-create-a-db-for-mongodb-container-on-start-up)

My question is, in my custom /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ init script, how can I reference env variables that are declared in docker-compose's .env file? Meaning, env variables besides MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD.

for example:

```
mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('sibling').createUser({user: '$SIBLING_USER', pwd: '$SIBLING_PASSWORD', roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'sibling' }]})"
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the following for an Reverse Proxy using NGINX where based on a env variable it loads a different config file.

Docker-compose.yml:

```
https-proxy:
build: 
  context: ./https-proxy
  dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
  args:
    - MY_VAR=TRUE
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

ARG MY_VAR
ENV MY_VAR=${MY_VAR}
RUN bash ./etc/nginx/config.sh
```

config.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $MY_VAR == true ]; then
    echo 'My Var is True'
else
   echo 'My Var is False'
```

You could also define an .env file aside your Docker-compose.yml, so you don't have to change that file and only define the values on a different place where Docker-compose will look for them