# Creating mongodb database and populating it with some data via docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I've the following script with a custom database specified but I don't see the database user getting created within the GUI (compass). I only see 3 default databases (admin, config, local).

I've looked into this [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912755/how-to-create-a-db-for-mongodb-container-on-start-up) answer but I need a specific answer for my question, please.

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0.10
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 27018:27018
      - 27019:27019
```

1. The expectation for a user database to be created.
2. Database prefilled with some records.

---

**Edit - made some progress, 2 Problems**

Added volumes

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:4.0.1r0
  container_name: mongo
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./assets:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

**1. Ignore**

Within assets folder, I've 3 files and I see this in the logs, my files are getting ignored.

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/file1.json

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/file2.json

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/file3.json
```

all my JSON files look like following. (no root array object? no `[]` at the root?)

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5d3a9d423b881e4ca04ae8f0" }, "name" : "Human Resource" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5d3a9d483b881e4ca04ae8f1" }, "name" : "Sales" }
```

**2. Default Database not getting created.** following line is not having any effect.

```
MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: mydb
```

Comment: Do you put your scripts in scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/?

Comment: please see my edits

Comment: @AppDeveloper data should in `.js` or `.sh` file, rest will be ignored. you can look at the example I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All files `*.json` extension will be ignored, it should in `*.js`. Look into the documentation of mongo DB [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

**MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE**

> This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used
>   for creation scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js` (see
>   Initializing a fresh instance below). MongoDB is fundamental
>   designed for "create on first use", **so if you do not insert data with
>   your JavaScript files, then no database is created.**

**Initializing a fresh instance**

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
>   `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. Files will be executed in **alphabetical
>   order. .js** files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

you can look into this example

create folder data and place create_article.js in it

( in the example I am passing your created DB user)

```
db = db.getSiblingDB("user");
db.article.drop();

db.article.save( {
    title : "this is my title" , 
    author : "bob" , 
    posted : new Date(1079895594000) , 
    pageViews : 5 , 
    tags : [ "fun" , "good" , "fun" ] ,
    comments : [ 
        { author :"joe" , text : "this is cool" } , 
        { author :"sam" , text : "this is bad" } 
    ],
    other : { foo : 5 }
});

db.article.save( {
    title : "this is your title" , 
    author : "dave" , 
    posted : new Date(4121381470000) , 
    pageViews : 7 , 
    tags : [ "fun" , "nasty" ] ,
    comments : [ 
        { author :"barbara" , text : "this is interesting" } , 
        { author :"jenny" , text : "i like to play pinball", votes: 10 } 
    ],
    other : { bar : 14 }
});

db.article.save( {
    title : "this is some other title" , 
    author : "jane" , 
    posted : new Date(978239834000) , 
    pageViews : 6 , 
    tags : [ "nasty" , "filthy" ] ,
    comments : [ 
        { author :"will" , text : "i don't like the color" } , 
        { author :"jenny" , text : "can i get that in green?" } 
    ],
    other : { bar : 14 }
});
```

mount the `data` directory

```
docker run --rm -it  --name some-mongo -v /home/data/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/  -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=user     -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root     -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass  mongo:4.0.10
```

once container created you will be able to see the DBs,

[image]

Comment: oh so you have to write code like `db.article.save` for each record? so no json solution?

Comment: also any comments on the part 2 of my problem

Comment: seem from documentation, you can override entry point to deal with a json file.

Comment: the database will only be created if there is any file `/dockerentrypoint.d` otherwise no database will be created. see documentation

Comment: `db = db.getSiblingDB("employeeadmin");`, on a side note, db seems to be global object, but then here it gets re-assigned from whatever `getSiblingDB` returns?

Comment: you can try without it, i provide it just an example to make your point clear

Comment: Thanks for the answer, quick question btw, for instance in your example `comments` field lists `author` name, how about if I want to add another field `_id`  of the author and include with `comments`. Is that how's its usually done in document databases, if then how would you do that. I'm new to JSON docs and coming from the relational background.

Comment: are you asking about something like `comments : [ { author :"will" , text : "i don't like the color" ,author_id:1}`

Comment: yes or put simply use the generated value from an earlier insert, it'd look like `comments : [ { _id: "5d3bc38b18f5f0b3ca543822", author :"will" , text : "i don't like the color"}]`, like primary key and foreign key from traditional/relational db systems.

Comment: I found a video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cYT0Qbu9tU please let me know if if I should know something else too