# How to initialize a new user and database for mongodb on docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

So, currently I have a `docker-compose.yml` file that has the following:

```
version: "2"
services:
 pastime:
   build:
     context: ./pastime
     dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
   volumes:
     - ./pastime:/usr/src/app
     - /usr/src/app/node_modules
   ports:
     - "3000:3000"
   depends_on:
     - mongo
   environment:
     - PORT=3000
     - DATABASE_USER=pastime
     - DATABASE_URL=mongo:27017
     - DATABASE_PASS=pastime123
     - DATABASE_NAME=pastime
   command: npm run start:dev
 mongo:
   image: mongo:latest
   restart: always
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   environment:
     - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=pastime
     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
     - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
   volumes:
     - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
```

And also my `init-mongo.js` file has:

```
db.createUser({
  user: 'pastime',
  pwd: 'pastime123',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: 'pastime'
    }
  ]
})
```

I am not sure why, but the output I get everytime when I do a `docker-compose logs -f mongo` comes up to:
`SASL SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication failed for pastime on admin from client 172.19.0.3:55568 ; UserNotFound: Could not find user "pastime"...`

I suspect that the init script is not running as I don't see kinds of logs about it in my mongo container.

Have followed a few examples, mainly following thru with this one:
[How to create a DB for MongoDB container on start up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912755/how-to-create-a-db-for-mongodb-container-on-start-up)

Comment: Could you post the container logs on startup? Please use `docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d; docker-compose logs -f`. On a quick glance looking at the entrypoint https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/4.2/docker-entrypoint.sh, it looks like what you have should work. I can see you are not mounting a data volume for mongo but any chance you added the `init-mongo.js` file after you initially started the container without destroying and recreating it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration you have posted above should work. I suspect that you may of started your containers prior to mounting the `init-mongo.js` under `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js` which is the result of the error.

Since you are not mounting a data volume for mongodb, you can simply just destroy and restart your containers using:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs -f
```

I actually was curious so copied your config and tested it successfully. See snippet from `docker-compose logs -f`:

```
mongo_1  | 2019-09-06T15:43:19.982+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn3] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:46874 conn3: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "4.2.0" }, os: { type: "Linux", name: "Ubuntu", architecture: "x86_64", version: "18.04" } }
mongo_1  | Successfully added user: {
mongo_1  |  "user" : "pastime",
mongo_1  |  "roles" : [
mongo_1  |      {
mongo_1  |          "role" : "readWrite",
mongo_1  |          "db" : "pastime"
mongo_1  |      }
mongo_1  |  ]
mongo_1  | }
```

I was able to exec into the container and connect to the db with that user:

```
$ docker-compose exec mongo bash
root@62ec89743bc0:/# mongo --username pastime --password pastime123 --authenticationDatabase pastime
MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=pastime&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("313dd5a9-c417-42c2-b35e-27b301e82def") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.0
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
> use pastime
switched to db pastime
>
```

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "2"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=pastime
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro

$ cat init-mongo.js
db.createUser({
  user: 'pastime',
  pwd: 'pastime123',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: 'pastime'
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Hey leeman, I am currently out and not with my workstation, will test it out asap! Thanks alot and will report my findings with you later on. Really appreciate the help and advice! Cheers!

Comment: Hey @leeman24, after I did a `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up -d`, it works.. Why didn't it work when I did this sequence tho?

1. `docker-compose up --build -d` // build and up containers
2. `docker-compose logs -f` // to view logs

Comment: @kyapwc, Unless you have your `history` available, I don't think we will know for sure but my hunch is that you initially started your containers without the `init-mongo.js` script mounted causing the database to initialize (which will not occur again until the container is destroyed as you don't have the volume mounted). If you run a `docker-compose down` and then a `docker-compose up --build -d`, this should work.

Comment: yeah, it all makes sense now that I think about it. I initially brought up the container without the `init-mongo.js` file present and only added that after bringing up the container. I just thought that when I run `docker-compose up --build -d` it would `down` the container by itself, my mistake. Thanks alot @leeman24 for the help! Really appreciate it! kudos to you mate

Comment: This demonstration is pretty much to it, for a notice that , `use <db name>` is work whatever the `<db name>` is, more appropriate way is to insert new collection check if database showed up.

Answer (score 3):

There is some correspondence with a couple of posts through Stack Overflow - I think this one is of interest and adds some insights in a very comprehensive way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522699/13232069

The emphasis is on the need to log on admin before creating a new user. In addition to a `docker-compose.yml` file, it would then look like (with a shell script - all credit goes to x-yuri):

init-mongo.sh:

```
mongo -- "$MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" <<EOF
    var rootUser = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME';
    var rootPassword = '$MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD';
    var admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
    admin.auth(rootUser, rootPassword);

    var user = '$MONGO_INITDB_USERNAME';
    var passwd = '$(cat "$MONGO_INITDB_PASSWORD_FILE")';
    db.createUser({user: user, pwd: passwd, roles: ["readWrite"]});
EOF
```

or with a mongo-init.js file :

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
// move to the admin db - always created in Mongo
db.auth("rootUser", "rootPassword");
// log as root admin if you decided to authenticate in your docker-compose file...
db = db.getSiblingDB('DB_test');
// create and move to your new database
db.createUser({
'user': "dbUser",
'pwd': "dbPwd",
'roles': [{
    'role': 'dbOwner',
    'db': 'DB_test'}]});
// user created
db.createCollection('collection_test');
// add new collection
```

That insight definitely unlocked me !

Comment: Thanks for your feed-back, I think it is an answer to the question and this link has a place here as it adresses the issue. It did help me a lot so I don't see harm in mentionning it here - I edited it to make it more self-structured. Hope it's better now :)