# Docker Compose MongoDB docker-entrypoint-initdb.d is not working

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I am using following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.7'
services:
 db_container:
  image: mongo:latest
  restart: always
  environment:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: root-db
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
  volumes:
    - ./database/initdb.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.js:ro
    - ./data:/data/db
```

Here is my initdb.js file

```
db.createUser(
{
  user: "api-test",
  pwd: "api-test",
  roles: [
    {
      role: "readWrite",
      db: "api-test"
    }
  ]
}
);
```

I can see only 3 databases  and unable to connect to `api-test` DB

[image]

Please help me if something is missing

Comment: You don't have `api-test` database. Do You need create first?

Comment: @Valijon I am trying to achieve whenever i run docker-compose up command it should create mongob image in the docker with api-test database and user

Comment: Try to change `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: root-db` to `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: api-test`. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912755/how-to-create-a-db-for-mongodb-container-on-start-up)

Comment: i have tried also dosn't work even i can't see the root-db in MongoDB compass

Comment: not even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944387/3710490) ? Try to enter inside docker image and run manually, maybe you got some permission issue

Comment: nope, I am trying using docker-compose file that one is Docker file

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Able to solve the issue with the help of the following article
[Docker-Compose mongoDB Prod, Dev, Test Environment](https://medium.com/@onexlab.io/docker-compose-mongodb-prod-dev-test-environment-eb1a75675f93)

The file structure should be

```
Project
├── docker-compose.yml (File)
├── docker-entrypoint-initdb.d (Directory)
│   ├── mongo-init.js (File)
```

**docker-compose.yml file**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   mongo:
    container_name: container-mongodb
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: root-db

    volumes:
      - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
```

**mongo-init.js** file

```js
print('Start #################################################################');

db = db.getSiblingDB('api_prod_db');
db.createUser(
  {
    user: 'api_user',
    pwd: 'api1234',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'api_prod_db' }],
  },
);
db.createCollection('users');

db = db.getSiblingDB('api_dev_db');
db.createUser(
  {
    user: 'api_user',
    pwd: 'api1234',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'api_dev_db' }],
  },
);
db.createCollection('users');

db = db.getSiblingDB('api_test_db');
db.createUser(
  {
    user: 'api_user',
    pwd: 'api1234',
    roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db: 'api_test_db' }],
  },
);
db.createCollection('users');

print('END #################################################################');
```

Comment: This throw an error within the container: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Answer (score 3):

Although my setup was correct, removed volumes, modified the db, etc, none of these worked for me.

The only way was to change the name of the mongodb container inside the docker-compose, instead of `mongo` I wrote `mongodb` and it worked.