# Error authenticating MongoCredential when trying to connect from spring boot docker container to mongo docker container?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, application.properties

I have the following `docker compose` file, for a `Spring boot container` that connects to a `mongoDB container`:

```
#
# APIs
#----------------------------------------------
  pokerstats:
    image: pokerstats
    container_name: pokerstats
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - db

#
# Utilities
#----------------------------------------------
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./database:/data
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: pokerStats
```

In my spring boot `application.properties` I have:

```
server.port=8080
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/pokerStats
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=pokerStats
```

When I try to hit my endpoint using Postman I get the below error:

```
{
        "timestamp": "2020-04-07T17:39:19.129+0000",
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "message": "Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='admin', source='pokerStats', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1, userName='admin', source='pokerStats', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties=<hidden>}",
        "path": "/rounds"
    }
```

Note that this was working fine before I added below to my docker compose file:

```
 environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: pokerStats
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding:

**application.properties:**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/pokerStats?authSource=admin
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database = admin
spring.data.mongodb.database=pokerStats
```

I believe that: `?authSource=admin` needs added to end of the mongo uri.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates the authSource is pokerStats. But the user is created in the admin database, according to [this](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/pull/145/files) which I found via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42912755/how-to-create-a-db-for-mongodb-container-on-start-up).

So, I'm assuming this configuration is not correct:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
```

I am not familiar with spring data so I don't know how to configure this correctly.