# Mongodb database could not be created on docker container startup

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to initialize Mongodb database with collection in it and its own new user.

I have followed the following [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944387/2393001) link but I am unable to connect to database from host.

If I open a  Mongodb Shell I am unable to find my newly created database and user.

**Scenario 1**

Docker File

```
FROM mongo:latest

ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME admin-user
ENV MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD admin-password
ENV MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE admin

ADD mongo-init.js /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

mongo-init.js

```
db.auth('admin-user', 'admin-password')

db = db.getSiblingDB('test-database')

db.createUser({
  user: 'test-user',
  pwd: 'test-password',
  roles: [
    {
      role: 'readWrite',
      db: 'test-database',
    },
  ],
});

db.foo.insert({ x: 1, y: 1 })
```

I have linux ubuntu. I have used the following commmands:

```
docker image build -t image1:1.0 .
docker run -d -p 27017-27019:27017-27019 --name image1 mongo
```

For above scenario `Neo Anderson` answer worked perfectly. Now I have another scenario:

**Scenario 2:**

If I try to connect with my container Mongodb outside from the container I am unable to connect. Failed to connect to `172.20.1.100:37019`. Though I have changed the run command as well to  `run -d -p 37017:27017-27019`.

Comment: Better to use docker-compose with express client instead of maintaining your own image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your `docker run` command.
You are building the image `image1:1.0` but you are running the container using the `mongo` image.
The `--name` defines the container name. The last argument from the `docker run` command refers to the image to be used.

**Run the container**:

```
docker run -d -p 27017-27019:27017-27019 --name my-awesome-container image1:1.0
```

**List the containers:**  you need the `containerID` to open a console in the next step:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
b48ba39b0d38        image1:1.0          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes       0.0.0.0:27017-27019->27017-27019/tcp   my-awesome-container
```

**Connect to my-awesome-container:**

```
docker exec -ti b48ba39b0d38 sh
```

**Connect to the DB using the following command:** (use *admin-password* when asked for the passowrd)

```
mongo --username admin-user
MongoDB shell version v4.2.8
Enter password: 
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("17b28c1e-edb7-4c41-93bd-bdc3abcb47a6") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.8
Server has startup warnings: 
2020-07-30T12:20:09.577+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2020-07-30T12:20:09.577+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2020-07-30T12:20:09.577+0000 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---

>
```

**List the databases:**

```
> show databases
admin          0.000GB
config         0.000GB
local          0.000GB
test-database  0.000GB
```

Enjoy using the test-database that you created with the `mongo-init.js`

Comment: Okay let me check and I will get back in a minute.

Comment: What should be inside `my-awesome-container` ? @NeoAnderson

Comment: That is the name you want to give, to the container. It is optional. Just remove it if this simplifies the things. Docker will automatically generate for that container. To clarify a bit: when you used `docker build` you created an image named `image1:1.0`. Later on, you can deploy as many containers as you want from that image. When you execute `docker run`, you have to specify the image name you want to use in the last place. In this case, your image has the name `image1:1.0`, according to the `docker build` command that you are showing.

Comment: So this is how I will open the mongo shell `docker exec -it 5ddb8e735761 bash`? Where 5ddb8e735761 is docker container ID

Comment: Correct. This was the first step. Next step is to see if your user and database were created

Comment: `show dbs` response is empty. I am unable to see even admin database.

Comment: Do I need authentication to see my database list?

Comment: Works on my end. I will be editing the answer in 5 minutes to explain how to authenticate as well.

Comment: It can be `admin-user` and `admin-password`  in `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` or it should be `root` for both of them?

Comment: Its awesome. Now I am trying to connect with my container mongodb from outside container. I have mentioned `37017:27017` ports but when I try to connect from my outside its not connecting

Comment: Let me explain it in detail in my question.

Comment: I think that asking how connectivity can be established from the outside world to your container changes the scope of your initial question and deserves a different post.

Comment: Sure I will post a different question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcomed. If you can't find the answer on SO in an existing post, add the link to your new question. I should be able to help. Thanks